# VBA: Search for a package

Tags: vba

I am not sure how to go about for the following problem with VBA

1. I have a list of packages. Each package is a group of Items and has a unique id. Same Item can be present in multiple packages.
2. Two packages cannot be identical.

Sample Data in Excel:

```
**PackageName    Item**
Package1       Item1
Package1       Item2
Package1       Item3
Package2       Item2
Package2       Item3
```

My Input in another sheet is

```
**Items**
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

The code should return the

```
PackageName as Package1
```

If my input is

```
Item2
Item3
```

It should return me

```
PackageName as Package2
```

I am not sure how to proceed in most efficient manner with a VBA code for this problem.

Appreciate some pointers

Regards

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can we assume your input in the other sheet (item1, item2, item3 etc) is ordered? Can items be repeated within the same group?  I am saying this because at present the only way I can see to work with this is to walk the list  and when the first repeated item is met, flag first group complete and/or start of second group. Proceed to the end in this way. Then loop over the segments matching the item groupings to your existing mappings. You could use initial buckets based on group sizes maybe with most likely group at start. Try different algorithmic ideas to find try to find best.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Dictionary` object:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim packagesDict As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim items As Variant
    With Worksheets("Input") 'reference "Input" sheet
        items = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value), " ") ' build wanted package items content string
    End With

    Set packagesDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Worksheets("Sample Data") 'reference "Sample Data" sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' loop through packages in referenced sheet column A cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            packagesDict(cell.Value2) = packagesDict(cell.Value2) & cell.Offset(, 1).Value2 & " " ' update current package content
            If Trim(packagesDict(cell.Value2)) = items Then ' if current package content matches wanted package items content then you've found the one
                MsgBox "Found: " & cell.Value2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

just change "Input" and "Sample Data" strings to your actual input and sample data sheets names

Comment: Hey Thank you .. It seems to work if
1. The items in Input are in the same order as in the Sample Data Sheet (Is there a tweak to make it order independent)
2. It also gives Package Name if the Partial Match is Found e.g. Input is Item1, Item2 - It will give Package1 even though Package1 only consists of Item1 Item2 Item3. (Not sure if we can make it exact Match)

Appreciate the help - Thanks